# Why is my hover state not being removed by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Here is a fiddle for you: [Click me](http://jsfiddle.net/fc0y6dk3/).

I currently want to remove a hover state on click, and I did some research here, finding out that most people suggest jquerys `.removeClass()` as the easiest way to do this.

However, this just wont work for me. I tried to give my selector the class, or the ID, whatever I try, it just won't work.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `:hover` is not a class. Removing `topmenu` would work; but that won't be good.

Comment: May be worth including your example code in the question (just in case the link dies in the future).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since :hover is a selector and not a class, using .removeClass() won't work. You either have to completely use JS for that or disable that behaviour with another CSS class, like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fc0y6dk3/1/

```
<script>
    function unhover(){
        $('.topmenu').addClass("nope");        
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.topmenu:not(.nope):hover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Nice and easy. Perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

`:hover` is not a class, but it is fixable by adding a 2nd class and removing that as per your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc0y6dk3/2/), but updated

```
<div class="topmenu topmenu2">
    <button type="button" style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:50px" onclick="unhover()">OK</button>
</div>

<script>
    function unhover(){
    $('.topmenu').removeClass("topmenu2");        
}
</script>

.topmenu, .topmenu2{
    width: 500px;
    height:100px;
    background: grey;
}

.topmenu2:hover{
    background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i might be late in giving the answer but if you want here is the link

http://jsfiddle.net/Saiyam/fc0y6dk3/4/

What i have don is instead of `removeClass` you can use `toggleClass` which will add and remove class on click.